# JSON data to select list only specific keys

Tags: jquery, json, select

This is the JSON data that is returned:

```
[{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":2.332,"NAME":"Coal","ID":812,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Metric tons"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":0.002705,"NAME":"Diesel","ID":816,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Liters"},{"ENERGYUSE":26635048.359808,"EMISSIONFACTOR":0.0005703,"NAME":"Electricity","ID":811,"UNITOFMEASURE":"KWH"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":0.002705,"NAME":"Fuel Oil","ID":814,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Liters"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":0.002328,"NAME":"Gasoline","ID":815,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Liters"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":0.002603,"NAME":"Jet Fuel","ID":818,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Liters"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":0.00269,"NAME":"Kerosene","ID":817,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Liters"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":0.001509,"NAME":"LPG\/Propane","ID":813,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Liters"},{"ENERGYUSE":523846.2564,"EMISSIONFACTOR":0.05307,"NAME":"Natural Gas","ID":810,"UNITOFMEASURE":"million BTU"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":0.285618,"NAME":"Wood","ID":819,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Kilograms"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":"","NAME":"Other","ID":808,"UNITOFMEASURE":""}]
```

I am looking to get only the NAME and ID from the JSON string into a select list using jquery.
So for example the select would look something like this when populated:

```
<select id="EnergyList" name="EnergyList">
 <option value="813">Nataural Gas</option>
 <option value="812">Coal</option>
  etc etc...
</select>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appeciated.Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a jQuery you can dynamically append the options based on the parsed json source.

```
var items = JSON.parse(jsonSource);

var $selectElement = $("#EnergyList");

$(items).each(function(){
    var newOption = '<option value="' + this.ID + '">' + this.NAME + '</option>';
    $selectElement.append(newOption);
});
```

See working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4m4b/)

Based on ankur's comment on optimisation see below the more optimised version:

```
var items = JSON.parse(jsonSource);

var $selectElement = $("#EnergyList");
var newOptions = '';

for(index = 0; index < items.length; index++)
{
    newOptions += '<option value="' + items[index].ID + '">' + items[index].NAME + '</option>';
}

$selectElement.append(newOptions);
```

See working optimised [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4m4b/1/)

Purely for completness on the optimisation topic, see the test results on all 4 variations, comparing for vs each and individual append vs appending the complete set.
Off course `for loop` and appending the complete set as ankur pointed out executes the fastest.

jsPerf [**Test-Results**](http://jsperf.com/for-vs-each-and-append-single-vs-complete)

Comment: I would suggest creating the whole markup and then appending it in single shot. Otherwise with this approach, we'll end up updating DOM for every option.

Comment: @ankur: To optimise the code you are indeed correct and in addition a plain javascript `for i =0; ...` would be faster again than the `.each()` as well.

Comment: Cool.....didn't know about the jsPerf.. +1 for enlighting us.. added a test case thats slichtly faster by just joining strings...http://jsperf.com/for-vs-each-and-append-single-vs-complete/2

Comment: @Steen: I love jsPerf, gets one thinking and is fun to mess around with. Nice addition.

Comment: Just wanted to say thankyou to everyone who contributed here, I now have it working according to the code given, JC

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse(data)`, to convert JSON string to Object. Then `JsonObj.Name`, `JsonObj.ID` or whatever you need, you can get from the object.

For your code

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(yourJson);
var optionTemplate = '<option value = "@@ID@@">@@NAME@@</option>';
var finalTemplate = '';
$.each(jsonObj, function(){
    tmp = optionTemplate;
    tmp = tmp.replace("@@NAME@@",this.NAME).replace("@@ID@@",this.ID);
    finalTemplate += tmp;
});
finalTemplate = '<select id = "EnergyList" name = "EnergyList">' + finalTemplate + '</select>';
console.log($(finalTemplate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this??

```
var Url = "/feedpage.aspx";
var jsonObjectInstance = $.parseJSON(
    $.ajax({
         url: Url,
         async: false,
         dataType: 'json'
        }
    ).responseText
);
var str ='<select id="EnergyList" name="EnergyList">';



for (var i = 0; i < jsonObjectInstance.length; i++) {
 str += '<option value="'+jsonObjectInstance[i].ID+'">'+jsonObjectInstance[i].NAME+'</option>'; 
}
str+='</select>';
$("#divToInsertIn").html(str);
```

Note:

You probably alrady have the get data part.. And I've used async to get data for no particular reason....

Answer (score 0):

If your script returns JSON data anyway, you can let jQuery parse it directly for you:

```
$.getJSON({
    url: yourAjaxUrl,
    data: yourData,
    success: function(jsonData) {
        insertOpts(jsonData);
    }
});

var insertOpts = function(data) {
    var $select = $('yourSelect').clone(true); // clone the select box
    $.each(data, function(i, obj) { // generate all the options temporarily in jQuery
        var $option = $select.append('<option />');
        $option.val(obj.ID).text(obj.NAME);
    });
    $('yourSelect').replaceWith($select); // replace the existing select with its manipulated clone
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json=[{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":2.332,"NAME":"Coal","ID":812,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Metric tons"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":0.002705,"NAME":"Diesel","ID":816,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Liters"},{"ENERGYUSE":26635048.359808,"EMISSIONFACTOR":0.0005703,"NAME":"Electricity","ID":811,"UNITOFMEASURE":"KWH"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":0.002705,"NAME":"Fuel Oil","ID":814,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Liters"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":0.002328,"NAME":"Gasoline","ID":815,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Liters"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":0.002603,"NAME":"Jet Fuel","ID":818,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Liters"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":0.00269,"NAME":"Kerosene","ID":817,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Liters"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":0.001509,"NAME":"LPG\/Propane","ID":813,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Liters"},{"ENERGYUSE":523846.2564,"EMISSIONFACTOR":0.05307,"NAME":"Natural Gas","ID":810,"UNITOFMEASURE":"million BTU"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":0.285618,"NAME":"Wood","ID":819,"UNITOFMEASURE":"Kilograms"},{"ENERGYUSE":"","EMISSIONFACTOR":"","NAME":"Other","ID":808,"UNITOFMEASURE":""}]
 $("#EnergyList").empty()
 $.each(json,function(i,o),function(){
   $("#EnergyList").append('<option value="'+o.ID+'">'+o.NAME+'</option>')  
 })
```